# Integrating Search Form for Google Maps

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps

I am building a search form using Google Maps Javascript V3 API. After performing a search, the code I have below passes the geocoordinates successfully but the map does not update. I tried moving the codeAddress function inside initialize() but then the search button didn't work. How do I integrate the two correctly?

### HTML:

```
<form>    
<input type="text" name="address" id="address" />
<input type="button" class="search_button" value="" onclick="codeAddress()" />    
</form>
```

### JavaScript:

```
var geocoder;
function initialize() {
  geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
  var mapOptions = {
    center: { lat: 48.509532, lng: -122.643852}
  };

  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),mapOptions);
  var locations = <?php echo json_encode($locations_array); ?>;
  var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

  var marker, i;

  for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {  
    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]),
      animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
      map: map
    });

    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
      return function() {

        var content = '';
        infowindow.setContent(content);
        infowindow.open(map, marker);
      }
    })(marker, i));
  } 

}

function codeAddress() {
  var address = document.getElementById('address').value;
  geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address}, function(results, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
      alert(results[0].geometry.location);
      map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        map: map,
        position: results[0].geometry.location
      });
    } else {
      alert('Please try again: ' + status);
    }
  });
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your main problem is that your map variable is local to the initialize function, so it is not available in the global scope where HTML click functions run.

**One solution:**

```
var geocoder;
var map;

function initialize() {
    geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    var mapOptions = {
        center: {
            lat: 48.509532,
            lng: -122.643852
        },
        zoom: 4
    };

    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);
```

[working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xa727gz4/1/)

**Another solution:**

define codeAddress inside the initialize function and use the google.maps.event.addDomListener function:

```
google.maps.event.addDomListener(document.getElementsByClassName('search_button')[0],'click',codeAddress);
```

[working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xa727gz4/2/)